# How to ignore required fields in ACF ( Advanced Custom Fields ) plugin for DRAFT status in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have ACF ( Advanced Custom Fields ) fields in WordPress website. The form the very lengthy. So it  will take time to fill all the details for Admin user.
I need to ignore require validation when the post status is DRAFT or Will be DRAFT.

So that Admin can save data and come back later and fill the data.
The validation needs to be work only when the post status is not DRAFT.

I have tried this function but it is not working properly.
`

```
add_action('acf/validate_save_post', 'clear_all_errors', 10, 0);
function clear_all_errors() {
   acf_reset_validation_errors();
}
```

`